# CSS - Keep Table Cell from Expanding and Truncate Long Text

Tags: html, css

Can someone please tell me why this is not truncating the text? the last cell just keeps growing. I don't want cells to grow beyond their allowed percentage.

```html
<HTML>
    <TABLE id=section1 width="100%">
        <TBODY>
            <TR style="TEXT-OVERFLOW: ellipsis; DISPLAY: table-cell; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; FONT-SIZE: 12px; OVERFLOW: hidden;">
                <TD style="WIDTH: 8%;  TEXT-OVERFLOW: ellipsis; DISPLAY: table-cell; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; FONT-SIZE: 12px; OVERFLOW: hidden;">COL A</TD>
                <TD style="WIDTH: 18%; TEXT-OVERFLOW: ellipsis; DISPLAY: table-cell; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; FONT-SIZE: 12px; OVERFLOW: hidden;">COL B</TD>
                <TD style="WIDTH: 22%; TEXT-OVERFLOW: ellipsis; DISPLAY: table-cell; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; FONT-SIZE: 12px; OVERFLOW: hidden;">COL C</TD>
                <TD style="WIDTH: 14%; TEXT-OVERFLOW: ellipsis; DISPLAY: table-cell; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; FONT-SIZE: 12px; OVERFLOW: hidden;">COL D</TD>
                <TD style="WIDTH: 12%; TEXT-OVERFLOW: ellipsis; DISPLAY: table-cell; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; FONT-SIZE: 12px; OVERFLOW: hidden;">COL E</TD>
                <TD style="WIDTH: 10%; TEXT-OVERFLOW: ellipsis; DISPLAY: table-cell; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; FONT-SIZE: 12px; OVERFLOW: hidden;">COL F</TD>
                <TD style="WIDTH: 12%; TEXT-OVERFLOW: ellipsis; DISPLAY: table-cell; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; FONT-SIZE: 12px; OVERFLOW: hidden;">COL G</TD>
                <TD style="WIDTH: 4%;  TEXT-OVERFLOW: ellipsis; DISPLAY: table-cell; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; FONT-SIZE: 12px; OVERFLOW: hidden;">LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG</TD>
            </TR>
        </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
</HTML>
```

Here is a [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsmgD/)

Comment: please paste some context code or jsFiddle this.

Comment: @EliranMalka that is the relevant code. I can't use jscript.

Comment: I know all caps html _works_ but this code is **screaming**...

Comment: @JKirchartz It's machine generated sorry :(

Comment: @Pepe - well, you should scream back at that machine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add `word-wrap: break-word` to your cell style..

Though you should really avoid inline styles and declare a class for the cells..

updated:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/achusonline/hsmgD/6/)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I agree on the inline styles but I have no conrol over that.

Comment: can you check the updated jsfiddle out.. first of all of you should not keep `overflow: hidden`, you wont be able to see any text longer than the width of that cell..

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in the latest Chrome (32.x) or Firefox (26).

Comment: @GregPettit - do you have proof for this? it does on my ubuntu.

Comment: What do you mean, "proof"? I load the jsfiddle up in the environment described and the text is not truncated. I hardly need to take a screenshot of that. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Just for correctness sake, I updated the solution suggested by @redDevil to adhere to **modern web standards**:

#### Markup

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="a">COL A</td>
            <td class="a">COL B</td>
            <td class="a">COL C</td>
            <td class="a">COL D</td>
            <td class="a">COL E</td>
            <td class="a">COL F</td>
            <td class="a">COL G</td>
            <td class="b">LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Styles

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #35f;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
td.a {
    width: 13%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
td.b {
    width: 9%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

#### Live

Here's a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/e4Npt/) on jsFiddle

#### Please be noted

1. A large part of the solution is setting the `table-layout: fixed;` on the table element.
2. The other part - well you know it - is providing the long cell with `word-wrap: break-word;`, and removing the `overflow: hidden;` rules.

Comment: Somewhere along the way, this either stopped working in Chrome for Windows or has never worked.

Comment: @GregPettit - truth be told - i've only tested this on ubuntu chromium and firefox, not on a windows machine. it still works for me.

Comment: In the jsFiddle provided, if I change the styles for "td.a" to apply ONLY to "td" (delete the ".a") it works. But not as provided. In other words, forget about the "a" and "b" classes for the most part-- it's the td element that needs the "nowrap".

Comment: @GregPettit - changing `td.a` to `td` seem to break it rather fixing it. please provide the OS version as well as the browser's, so I can try and reproduce this. Thanks for the feedback and for taking the time to comment this out.

Comment: Eliran, I tried it in Windows 8, Windows Server (2007), and Ubuntu 12.04. On the Ubuntu box it work in neither Firefox nor Chrome. On the Windows boxes, it works in neither Firefox nor Chrome. I could try a Mac box as well... but I'm suspecting that having it NOT work is the more common scenario.

Comment: uhm.. not in my case. weird. what's your definition of *working* anyhow? can you link to a snapshot so i can view the rendered result?

Comment: Ahhhh.... it's probably working as designed after all. The original question asks for the text to be truncated. It's not being truncated. It is growing the cell vertically. I was hung up on truncation and didn't notice that you're providing an alternative to what was asked, allowing the cell to grow in height but not width. Regardless, I'll own that it's my lack of careful examination that had me concluding it was broken.

Comment: ok man, anyhow, thanks for taking the time to point out what you thought was broken.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you will need to have a display:block element for the overflow to work properly.

The easiest way to do this, if you need to use tables, is to add a  inside each of your elements with the style on it.

I'll post an example of what I am talking about.

Comment: After digging a bit further, the table cells aren't taking the width your are applying. If you used actual px measurements it starts working, but the browser is having trouble calculating the width of the columns properly. Tables are no fun.